# How to evaluate this limit with $\infty$

Tags: limits

I have this problem:

$$\frac{2}{3}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\frac{m\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{m+2}-(m+1)\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{m+1}+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)^{2}}$$

My instructor told that one can't talk about $\infty-\infty=0$.

So, how to work with this limit problem?

Comment: Show that each of the first two terms on top dies. Once you have done the first, you can say "in the same way $\dots$"

Comment: Notice, $a x \exp(-bx) \to 0 \quad (x\to\infty) \quad \forall\ a\in\mathbb R, b\in\mathbb R^+$

Comment: Can you please elaborate your "answers"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{2}{3}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\frac{m\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{m+2}-(m+1)\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{m+1}+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)^{2}}$$

now lets ONLY look at $$m\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{m+2}$$
$3^{m+2}$ will approach infinity a LOT faster than $m$ will as $m$ approaches infinity, so as m approches infinity $m\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{m+2}$ will approach $0$

now lets ONLY look at $$(m+1)\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{m+1}$$
again $3^{m+1}$ will approach infinity a LOT faster than $m+1$ will as $m$ approaches infinity, so as m approches infinity $(m+1)\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{m+1}$ will approach $0$

now we evaluate it:
$$\frac{2}{3}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\frac{m\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{m+2}-(m+1)\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{m+1}+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)^{2}}$$
$$= \frac{2}{3}*\frac{0+0+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)^{2}}$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}*\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{2}}$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}*\frac{1}{3}*\frac{9}{4}$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Many many thanks:)

Comment: OOPS!! it should be half!! $\frac{1}{2}$ as your calculations suggest.

Comment: sorry for the calculation mistake, i have corrected it now